# How to run regTermTest on every coefficient in a regression model in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I want to run a Wald test to evaluate the statistical significance of each coefficient in the model using the `regTermTest` function of the `survey` package (as described [here](https://mathewanalytics.com/2015/09/02/logistic-regression-in-r-part-two/)).

The syntax of `regTermTest` calls for the `model` followed by the `test.terms`, but if you list multiple test terms it seems to evaluate them all together rather than separately.

```
library(caret) # for the GermanCredit sample dataset
data(GermanCredit)
mod1 <- glm(Class ~ Age + as.factor(ForeignWorker) + Property.RealEstate + Housing.Own + CreditHistory.Critical, data = GermanCredit, family = binomial(link='logit'))
library(survey)
regTermTest(mod1, c("Age", "ForeignWorker", "Property.RealEstate", "Housing.Own", "CreditHistory.Critical"))
#
```

Of course, I could separate them out this way, but it's clunky and repetitive (i.e. the following code produces the desired result but is inefficient when dealing with lots of variables):

```
regTermTest(mod1, "Age")
regTermTest(mod1, "ForeignWorker")
regTermTest(mod1, "Property.RealEstate")
regTermTest(mod1, "Housing.Own")
regTermTest(mod1, "CreditHistory.Critical")
```

I've tried extracting the coefficient names into a vector and inserting it into a `for` loop, but it didn't work (it combines all the terms into one evaluation rather than separately estimating their importance):

```
vars <- names(mod1$coefficients)
vars <- vars[-1]
for (i in 1:length(vars)) {
     iv = vars[i]
     rtest <- regTermTest(mod1, iv)
}
```

How can I efficiently code this?

Comment: *it didn't work*...we often get this unhelpful remark. What was the error or undesired result?

Comment: The undesired result is that it combines all the terms into one evaluation rather than separately estimating their importance. I've edited the question to add this information.

Comment: Yes, saving the results in a list or other object would be desirable.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify this. The line-by-line code was the desired result--it's easy to do, but poor programming as it's repetitive. I'm looking for a better solution than copying and pasting code and changing variable names manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Updated)**

The `*apply` family can help, depending on how you want things to look.

```
lapply(names(mod1$model)[-1], function(x) regTermTest(mod1, x))

sapply(names(mod1$model)[-1], function(x) regTermTest(mod1, x))
```

You'll have a bit of work to do if you wanted to display the results in a nice way.

**(Explanation of update).**

The original solution just followed the questioner's idea to use `names(mod1$coefficients)`. But that won't work if there is a factor variable, since `mod1$coefficients` will contain the name(s) of the variable concatenated with non-default values in the way `R` regression models always deal with categorical variables. That confuses `regTermTest` because it goes looking for a variable in the dataset that doesn't exist so it returns a baffling error message.

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked on the sample data but gave an error on my real data: `Error in solve.default(V) : 'a' is 0-diml`. I realized this was because my actual data contained factors but the sample data did not. I've updated the sample data set above with this dilemma. I apologize, but do you know any tweaks to your code that would accept regression formulas with factor variables (as per the updated sample data above)?

Comment: What's supposed to happen for factor variables? I do not believe wald stats can run on categorical variables. Consider then a `tryCatch` to return NAs for those problem elements: `sapply(names(mod1$coefficients)[-1], function(x) tryCatch(regTermTest(mod1, x), error = function(e) NA))`

Comment: I don't know why but `regTermTest` on a factor variable on my real data works fine: `regTermTest(mod1, "ForeignWorker")` where `ForeignWorker` is a factor. However, I cannot get it to work with the sample data above when I factor `ForeignWorker` there. I see someone else has had the same `Error in solve.default(V) : 'a' is 0-diml` error when using `regTermTest`, but didn't seem to find a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216353/r-error-in-solve-defaultv-a-is-0-diml-in-regtermtest-function

Comment: `regTermTest` works fine with factor variables. Where it gets confused is when you give it a variable name that isn't in the dataset. See my edited answer for an explanation of what is going on.